# Applying transform:scale to just the background image

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to achieve a classy zoom in effect on a div's background image with background-size:cover using transform:scale.

The problem I am facing is that the scale seems to enlarge the div as the background-image zooms in.

Is there a way to only apply the effect to the background image? Or am I doing something wrong?

```css
.despre-noi-image {
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2017/04/18/16/wine-evening.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: left;
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  -webkit-animation: zoomin 10s linear;
  animation: zoomin 10s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="despre-noi-image">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<!-- despre-noi-image -->
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to say is not clear. Please try to say in simple words.

Comment: I am trying to get a simple zoom in effect on the background image. the code above is what I used to get the effect. I would like the div to have the same width and height. But once the background zooms in, the div becomes larger. I think you will understand from the jsfiddle

Answer (score 8):

CSS is very simple. You can change background size with a transition on hover instead of scaling.

```
.despre-noi-image {
    width: 40%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2017/04/18/16/wine-evening.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: all .7s;
}
.despre-noi-image:hover {
    transition: all 1s;
    background-size: 110%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Add new element */
.container{
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.despre-noi-image{
 width:100%;  /*change */
 height: 500px;
 background: url('https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2017/04/18/16/wine-evening.jpg') no-repeat center center;  
 -webkit-background-size: cover; 
 -moz-background-size: cover; 
 -o-background-size: cover; 
 background-size: cover; 
 text-align: left;
 background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 10s linear;
 animation: zoomin 10s linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="despre-noi-image">
  &nbsp;
  </div><!-- despre-noi-image -->

</div>
```

Is this what you want?

You just use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I tried that. Visually, It does seem to fix the problem, but my div is still larger, you just can't see it and once the container has other children in one occasion it affected them. Hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: @raduzrc Must use `background-image`?

Comment: I would like to use background-image, but if you have another solution I am opened to it.

Comment: @raduzrc Why you try to make `div` fixed?

Comment: @raduzrc If you need size of  fixed `div`, you can get `<div class="container">`'s size.

Comment: on my website, the container has 2 children. the container takes 100vw-355px, and the 2 children take 40% and 60%  out of the parent. The height is always 100vh for both parent and child. And this repeats throughout the site. In on example, where .despre-noi-image takes 60% and floats to the left, it expands over the other child. Hope this clears things!

Answer (score 1):

`background-size:cover`
won't work for you.

```
.despre-noi-image{
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2017/04/18/16/wine-evening.jpg') no-repeat center center;  

    background-size: 100%; 
    text-align: left;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 10s linear;
    animation: zoomin 5s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-origin:center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
       background-size: 100%; 
    }
    100% {
       background-size: 150%; 
    }

}
```

Updated Code

Comment: using background-size: 100%;  in keyframes will not make animation smooth. Instead use transform: scale(1);